# Share sub-project in git repository in another repo

Tags: visual-studio, git

I have a git repository containing a Visual Studio solution with several projects. I have another git repository (also VS) where I want to add one of the projects in the first repo:

```
Repo 1:
Project_1
Project_2
Project_3

Repo 2:
Project_4
Project_5
Project_1 (Same as Project_1 above)
```

Is it possible to share just one of the projects in the git repo with another git repository? When I work in the second repo I want to be able to do commit/pull/push to the project that belongs to the first repo, and when I open the first repo I want to be able to get the changes I made to the first project in the second repo.

I have looked at `git submodules` but I don´t think that would help me since I don´t want to extract the shared project from the first git repo into a separate one. I want to keep the first repo intact...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concern with `git submodules`. It would appear to be exactly the right thing for the setup you're describing.

Comment: So could just Project_1 be a submodule to Repo 2 but still be apart of Repo 1?

Comment: I couldn't get the formatting I wanted to explain my reply so I put it into an answer. Let me know if any part of it is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confused on the structure of a `git` repository. The way I would structure your project is to make a repository for each of the projects then add them to `Repo 1` and `Repo 2` super projects.

**Graphically**

```
Git                  # Main git project directory
  /Projects
    /Project_1       # Each one is its own Git repository
    /Project_2
    /Project_3
    /Project_4
    /Project_5

  /Repos             # The main repositories that utilize the projects
    /Repo_1          # The super project directory
      .gitmodules    # The .gitmodules file created by 'git submodules add'
        --> submodule with url=../../Projects/Project_1  # entry in .gitmodules
        --> submodule with url=../../Projects/Project_2
        --> submodule with url=../../Projects/Project_3
    /Repo_2
      .gitmodules
        --> submodule with url=../../Projects/Project_1
        --> submodule with url=../../Projects/Project_4
        --> submodule with url=../../Projects/Project_5
```

Since the `submodule` urls for `Project_1` point to the same location, when you `git push` in one of the `submodule` directories for `Repo_1` or `Repo_2` you're actually pushing the changes to the same project repository.

There are some gotchas about synchronizing changes across the two super projects as `git` allows for the same `submodule` in two different super repositories to point to different revisions. For more information (such as how to push, commit changes and update `submodules`) I recommend you checkout:

1. http://speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html
2. http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html